# Git submodule returns blank. Cannot use commands

Tags: git, github

I need to clone a repository from Github and am using Git Shell provided with the Github for Windows package.

The repository contains submodules and I don't know why, (first time) I cannot use submodule commands. They worked while ago but do not work anymore.. They just do not return anything.

I have tried all I could.

```
git submodule
git submodule init
git submodule update
```

All these 3 commands don't return anything.. Just blank.. And I am sure this project has a SteamKit2 submodule. I have cloned it before but I just deleted it and am re-cloning it and now this shit aint work.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qt2UE.jpg

Answer (score 0):

These commands to return blank if the current git directory does not have sub modules.  If `ls -a .gitmodules` returns nothing this is the case.  I just cloned the same repository and yes it did not have submodules.

I did find a revision on this repository that does have submodules:

```
git checkout -b mybranch b0a0fd6
git submodule update --init
```

Comment: So what should I do? Let  it be?

Comment: It is unclear to me what you need to do to build.  I checked the online documents and they still claim the use of git submodules.  I was simply explaining why the git commands were not functioning.  I would suggest skipping the submodule step and compile anyway.  If this produces errors post a new question.

Comment: Okay. I will try contacting the creator as well

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem. Apparently the project was mnigrated with NuGet packages so the 'submodules' were downloaded when you first built it.